# Windows not sending SET_CONFIGURATION while enumerating

Tags: c, usb

I'm attempting to get my USB driver to enumerate properly on Windows 7, but I'm experiencing some unexpected (to me) behavior.

Everything follows the expected order of operations - that is, Windows issues the following commands:

- Get_device_descriptor()
- Set_Address()
- Get_configuration_descriptor()

At this point, I expect Windows to provide the Set_configuration() command, but instead, it doesn't send anything and my device is shown as being enumerated.

Is there any reason why Windows would not send me the set_configuration command?

In case it will help, below is the configuration descriptor I'm using along with the relevant control flow.
NOTE: my usb analyzer gives me a warning about the wTotalLength field, but it doesn't seem to be correct/relevant
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of USB enumeration routines is implementation specific, and may follow slightly differing paths depending on the driver.  Your driver may be looking for additional information before it issues the Set_Configuration command.  Have you ***[seen this site](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_4.htm)***.  There are several parts.  Maybe something there can help.